# Глюк поиска в Excel 2016

Tags: excel, office

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, если делать поиск по таблице он находит и выделяет ячейку (к стати можно ли сделать это выделение более явным??) , и если в этом же окне поиска вбить новое значение то он его вроде как находит но не выделяет и никак на него не переключает, помогает только отскролить таблицу вверх или вниз и затем снова нажать найти, можно ли это где-то в настройках поправить?

Comment: Непонятно.Поиск с помощью чего? Как ищете? Сделать выделение более явным относительно чего? Прикрепите пример того, что получается и что не получается

Comment: Обычный поиск, CTRL+F, ищем в табличке значение через CTRL+V , видим что оно есть, делаем CTRL+V нового значения, ничего не происходит, хотя если сделать "Find all" то в списке появляется искомое значение, но даже клик по нему не приводит к каким-либо результатам, искать начинает только если кликнуть по самой табличке (не закрывая окно поиска, просто сменить фокус окна), а затем снова нажать на поиск, вот я думаю это баг или это можно отключить

Comment: ps: по поводу выделения, когда находит он выделяет ячейку, но если таблица большая, цветная и с границами на ячейках то приходится всматриваться где-же это найденное значение, можно ли выделение ячейки сделать "пожирнее"